# systemd apt pinned to -1 and installed in upgrade from Debian 8 to Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt, dist-upgrade

While in the process of migrating some servers from my testing network, a few of them installed `systemd`; I was a bit surprised as I am using sysV, and have systemd pinned to `-1`.

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems my `systemd` pinning to -1 was not enough. There are a couple more packages belonging to system to APT pin too.

So, I changed my `/etc/apt/preferences.d/01nosystemd` to:

```
Package: systemd
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: dh-systemd
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: systemd-shim
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: libpam-systemd
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

And also ran the commands:

```
sudo apt-mark hold systemd dh-systemd systemd-shim libpam-systemd
```

Additional note: `libsystemd0` is not forgotten, simply it cannot be avoided so easily, due to several dependencies.

Link: [linux.org wiki questions - Prevent systemd installation](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Prevent_systemd_installation#For_Debian_based_systems)

Comment: For a similar reason (systemd suddenly installed on top of sysv, trouble when booting) I tried switching to Devuan (for the moment only on one of my machines). Works fine so far.

Comment: AFAIK Devuan only supports Jessie - I am trying Stretch now; systemd has to be cleaned *before* booting.

Comment: [Naming](https://devuan.org/) is different on Devuan (for whatever reason): testing = ascii, unstable = ceres. I've only tried stable = Jessie, though. And if course systemd has to be removed to get a clean boot.